# Convert CSV files to Magento importable CSV

Tags: magento, csv, import

I have two CSV sheets that needs to be imported into Magento. Since magento CSV import has an default markup, i'm wondering how to convert these two CSV's into Magento importable CSV's.

So basically i need something that can convert diffrent CSV files to Magento importable CSV's.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is about [coding](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What [code did you try](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or in which language are you going to write it?

Comment: You could use Excel. That's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert manually based on Magento's default markup for import.